# How to disable system notifications using KNOX SDK or Airwatch?

Tags: android, kiosk-mode, airwatch, samsung-knox

I'm working on an application that uses Airwatch to enter the device into a single purpose device when only one app is opened for a user (not by Knox sealed mode) and also uses Knox SDK to manage device settings, etc.
I'd like to block system notifications when the app is in a kiosk mode (or it more preferably to block any notifications like a low-battery in any mode, not only a kiosk).
How can I do it using Knox SDK or can I do it using Airwatch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As from official Airwatch response: there no such functionality in Airwatch and an appropriate feature request has been created in the internal tracker.
Unfortunately, there are no any estimations because of internal feature prioritization should be done.